# Gratis web based project management and CRM tools for Electronics PCB/CAD design industry

Tags: gratis, web-apps, project-management

**Sorry my previous question has been put on hold and I can't edit to add more details. Here is my question again with more details added. Please delete my previous question. Thank you**

I know there are so many tools and web based applications which have emerged in recent years and I've done quite a lot research but found none which seems to be more specifically designed for Electronics and Electrical or not even any core engineering businesses.

For example...

I got a website and will take all my client orders from a web form. Once the client fills the required information with relevant files attached and click submit then the form data should go straight into online project management area. Also, sometimes it should allow admin or third user to create new order when a client is unable to do for some personal reasons.

From there coming to project management area, the application should analyse the details based on rule filters and then automatically create a folder structure with relevant files.Say folder structure should be something like this

- project folder
- original files
- assigned technician/ engineer folder
- documents
- fabrication outputs, etc..,

And from the folder structure, there should an option to hide certain folders to certain users.The size limits for some folders should be 10mb-1gb or even more.

Once the folders and details are logged correctly then admin will check the info and start assigning the jobs to the relevant engineers. As soon as he assigns there should be an email/SMS alerts to be sent to both client and engineer.

From there every update should be exchanged between client, supervisor and engineers. All the project notes should be able to get updated in real time.

I mean from the start of the job to the end of receiving clients feedback everything should go real time like a clock ticking.

This is my short list and I could go more and more but then it wouldn't be free or open source as I've to build my own stuff by paying loads to developers.

Anyways if you could just take me to something which can do at least some extent of my list that would be great.

Hope someone here would have already found one or, at least, guide me on the right path on how to make use of existing ones.

Answer (score 1):

You’ve mentioned a couple of aspects that are essential to any sales process and, obviously, you need sales automation solution that would match the specific needs of your business, electronics retail in this case. As far as I understood your question, you primarily focus on the orders automation issue. I can suggest you to check out [bpm’online sales](https://www.bpmonline.com/sales) This one has a lot of customization tools that will deliver a total control over the process of end-to-end sales.  For, instance, you can manage your orders in bpm’online with little to no effort as you can classify orders by account type (individuals or legal entities), group orders by stages, budgets, products or services, owners, etc. Monitor the current status of key orders and analyze the effectiveness of the order processing. Not to mention the single window where you can promptly process various orders and in-depth analytics on each individual case. But that’s just a fraction of what bpm’online is capable of, I’m sure you will be pleasantly surprised with its impressive features.